# Get updated x coord of frame of cell item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get `x` of frame of `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell` after setting text. I need this for adding some subview with background color to cell, so I need to know x and width of cell before cell displaying.

So, I set the new text for label in cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and try to get x of label frame:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cell.label.text = "new text"
        var x = CGRectGetMinX(cell.label.frame)
}
```

Of course I can't get **correct x of the updated label** exactly after setting new text, so I'm trying to get it in the `willDisplayCell`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      var x = CGRectGetMinX(cell.label.frame)      
}
```

but `var x` is still wrong.

This doesn't work too:

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!    

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var x = CGRectGetMinX(label.frame)
    }
}
```

Also, I want to note all these methods does not work during first displaying, but if I scroll some cells to the bottom and then scroll back to the top then upper cells are displayed correctly(and I get correct `x`).

How can I get correct `x` and `width` of cell before displaying for setting subview?

Comment: Much easier if you use auto-layout constraints... Any reason you don't want to?

Comment: @DonMag because I need get `x` of `label` for creating and adding layout to this cell as a background of this label. So, this is the main goal, if you can suggest how can I properly do this, I will approve this too

Comment: You don't need the x coordinate to add a view (or whatever) as a background of the label. If you use auto-layout, you can add your "new background subview" and tell it to auto-size itself to the size of the label... or a percentage of it... or however you want it to look, and the constraints will put it where it needs to go. If you show the code for what you are doing now, how it looks and how you *want* it to look, perhaps I can help.

Comment: @DonMag thanks, constraints - are absolutely correct solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting text of the label, try to layout label to get updated frame:

```
cell.label.text = "new text"
cell.label.layoutIfNeeded()  //layout label
var x = CGRectGetMinX(cell.label.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely correct answer on the asked question, but for anyone else who wants to draw some background for the cell, please check comments under my question.

Comment: i don't fully understand what you want to drow on background, i think you want something like this
cell.label.layoutIfNeeded()
labelBackgroundView.frame = cell.label.frame
cell.insertSubview(labelBackgroundView, belowSubview: cell.label)
//also if you need this keep attention for reusing cell

Comment: Yes, this is also the right way, and also more correct than my first thought